# Implementation of tickmarks

Tags: java, android, swipeview

Im searching for a tutorial or an implementation of tickmarks for swipe navigation like this is mentioned on http://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/descendant-lateral.html in figure 7. Im searching for this simple style with filled quarters to indicate the current view the user is on.

If there is no implementation by now, any thoughts how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is is an implementation for the same, and already library is available, too.

Android ViewPagerIndicator :

- http://viewpagerindicator.com/
- https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

For implementation of tickmarks for swipe navigation, use "SampleCirclesWithListener" class from library.

Comment: Ive already seen this one but I didnt know there were that many styling options yet :) thx